# Can Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor use query parameters in allow?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Can anyone explain to me why the following code does not find any links to follow?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item

class CoursesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "courses"
    allowed_domains = ["test.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://golfpiste.com/kentat/?p=seuralista"
    ]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"kentat/esittely/\?lang=fi",unique=True),callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
    item =  Item()
    return item
```

The problem is that allow=r"kentat/esittely/\? will find the links to follow but soon as I add any query parameters it does not find any links even though kentat/esittely/?lang=fi links are certainly there.

So I'm left wondering if SgmlLinkExtractor can even have query parameters in "allow" or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to scrape golfpiste.com? I just tried the following URL in a browser and I didn't see any obvious link beyond the top navigation bar. (http://golfpiste.com/kentat/esittely/?lang=fi)

Comment: Well yes I am and you're right the starting url is wrong. :-o Oh brother, don't I feel stupid now. :-D

Comment: So does that mean the code is all working?

Comment: Yes, the actual start url  is http://golfpiste.com/kentat/?p=seuralista which I actually was using already. Wrote it wrong here for some reason. In any case the actual problem was that the rule was incorrect. The query params were mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting url and  link extractor rule were wrong. The rule should have been "kentat/esittely.\?seura=".